# Using views in Phalcon Task

Tags: phalcon

for one of my developments, I would like to run a Phalcon task that can retrieve the HTML code of a .volt view. The purpose of using a .volt view is to pass parameters to my .volt view before retrieving the HTML code. However, I have not found any discussion about this way of doing things, hence the reason why I am coming to you. And I wanted to know if it is possible to use .volt views in a Phalcon task.

PS:I am currently using version 3.4.5 of Phalcon

I tried this :

```php
public class TestTask {
    public function mainAction() {
        $diViews = $this->getDI()->get("view");
        $diViewsBackend->start();
        $diViewsBackend->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
        $diViewsBackend->render("test", 'test', $dataForReport);
        $diViewsBackend->finish();
        echo $diViewsBackend->getContent();
    }
}
```

But in my view .volt, I use `stylesheet_link` which generated this error : `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stylesheetLink() on null`

Thanking you in advance for the help you could give me

**Update of 20/03 to answer Arthur :**
Register service :

```
$di->set(
            'viewGvReport',
            function () {
                $viewGvReport = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple();
                $viewGvReport->setViewsDir(__DIR__ . '/views/');

                $viewGvReport->registerEngines(
                    array(
                        ".volt" => function ($view, $di) {
                            $volt = new Volt($view, $di);

                            $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
                            $compiler->addFunction('ucfirst', function($params) {
                                return "mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( $params, 0, 1 )) . mb_substr( $params, 1 )";
                            });
                            $compiler->addFunction('stylesheetLink', function($parameters, $local) {
                                return null;
                               return \Phalcon\Tag::stylesheetLink($parameters, $local);
                            });
                            return $volt;
                        }
                    )
                );

                return $viewGvReport;
            },
            true
        );
```

In Task :

```
$html = $this->view->render(
      "controller", "view", []
);
```

In my view .volt :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ stylesheet_link('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:200,200i,400,500&amp;subset=latin-ext') }}
    {{ stylesheet_link('assets2/css/report.min.css?version=2.9.4') }}
    <title>Report</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- content body with some with some expected parameters -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Task` is used for Phalcon\CLI. If you want to render html is better to use Phalcon MVC or MIcro.

Comment: @Arthur the problem is that for technical reasons I have to use the CLI to generate HTML so I don't see how to do it without using a Task

Comment: If you can share the technical reasons maybe we can find an alternative approach. If it really has to be with Cli, then first you have to change the type of View to use: go for 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple` (https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/views#simple-rendering) or pick a view (https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/views#picking-views). Where do you plan to render the generated HTML?

Comment: @Arthur I apologize for answering so late. to give more details in fact, my development is to perform a task that will be launched via a cron every week in order to generate pdf reports (this explains the reason for going through the CLI). these pdf reports will be generated via a html code and I would need to put in this html code elements in a dynamic way where goes my desire to go through the views of Phalcon.

Comment: Hi @Mathieu, no worries, I'll place a formal answer and we can continue solving the issue in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the Simple View service:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple as SimpleView;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt;

$di->set(
'view',
function () {
    $view = new View();

    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

    $view->registerEngines(
        [
            '.volt' => Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt::class
        ]
    );

    return $view;
  }
);

//In CLI, you must register as well the Tag service:
$di['tag'] = function () {
   return new Phalcon\Tag();
};

//and probably you will need the Url service too:

$di->set(
'url',
function () {
    $url = new Phalcon\Mvc\Url();

    $url->setBaseUri('/');

    return $url;
 }
```

);

And in the `Action` of your Task, you can pick up the view and return the code as string:

```
 public class TestTask {
  public function mainAction() {
      $html = $this->getView('Main/test', $dataForReport);
      //generate PDF
  }

  private getView($view, $dataForReport)
  {
       return $this->view->render(
        $view, ['data' => $dataForReport]
       );
  }
}
```

It is split in a private function in case you need to generate more views. Otherwise, leave it in one line in your mainAction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have an error when I use your method : 

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Parameter 'actionName' must be a string

This error is thrown in the return of your function "getView"

Comment: I change a little the function getView with this : return $this->view->render(
            "controller", "actionName", $params] ); But I have this error : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stylesheetLink() on null

Comment: That's partially good news, it means that you have managed to enter the view. The error is in the view itself, maybe you can share the code of it? Just for testing, you can comment the tag and see what happens as well.

Comment: BTW, just changed the code of the `action` and added the `voltService` in the DI (I forgot that you are rendering volt templates).

Comment: i shared my code in my first question in this post : [update_question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75720929/20583776)

Comment: Both functions in the DI declaration are redundant: `stylesheet_link` is native to Volt, and the default PHP `ucfirst` will return exactly the same of the declared function; so you can safely remove those lines and see what happens. Also, for performance reasons, it's better if you precompile Volt templates. Also, in the first `stylesheet_link` add `false` as second parameter, since the link is external.

Comment: I remove the redundant declaration and I add false in `stylesheet_link` but I always have the following error : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stylesheetLink() on null on the first  `stylesheet_link`. It seems that the native functions of volt are not able to load

Comment: I just changed the `$view->registerEngines` code in the example plus added the `Tag` and `Url` services: as you pointed out, the CliDI FactoryDefault does not include them, so it won't recognize the Tag calls. I just tried it with 3.4.5 CLI and it works, let me know how does it go for you.

Comment: Hello @Arthur, thanks it WORKS ^^ But I have one more problem and then I don't bother you anymore. The line $this->view->render() throw me the following warning : PHP Notice: ob_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in [my file task]

Comment: Glad that it works, it was a nice challenge :-) The error that you are receiving seems to be more related with the library that you are using to generate the PDFs. The script above works fine with Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.2.

Comment: Ok I will check that for the generation PDF. Thanks a lot for your help :) you got me out of a difficult situation

Comment: With pleasure Mathieu --and enjoy Phalcon!